# Computing paths of length n through linked objects

Tags: algorithm, f#

I have a set of x objects that have links to at least one of other objects in the set. I need to compute every combination of paths of length n that is possible by following the links with the given set of objects. Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Do you need a count, or do you need a data structure representing them, or do you need the actual list?  Be warned, the actual list grows exponentially with `n`.

Comment: An actual list would be ideal, n doesn't need to be very large

Comment: The algorithm you're looking for is a depth-limited [depth-first-search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: If you want to get a more detailed answer than the above comment, you'll need to post a code sample showing how you represent your objects and what you tried so far to solve the problem...